# Facebook "like" give me the logo of the site however I want a different Image to appear

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

When I  click on the link button on my website , I get the notification on Facebook that I have liked such and such thing and along with that my Logo of the website Appears. However I want that the logo of the website is not shown but instead the  Image  of the product is shown.

I am using the step 1 like button on this URL https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at open graph meta tags and in particular the image tag. `og:image`.

A full example of tags and how they work can be found here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ but the general jist of what you need is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Movie Website</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My Movie Website"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://mymovies.com/images/logo.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Movies"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="Some content description blah..."/>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

By setting this tag it should tell Facebook the image to load. You can test this via Facebooks tools online here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: These tags have to be placed in the Head , But the Image I want is generated by the PHP and is placed in the Body . What can I do to load that Pic ?

Comment: One way or the other Facebook needs a URL to load the image. If you build the image via some PHP image library, you could build it and cache it OR create a script that returns an image via url e.g. http://site.com/imagebuilder.php?pictureId=123

Comment: I didnt get you .

I manually Created the cataloge , My produce say a "car". Is there on the URL with the discription and image of the car at url: `www.example.com/products.php?id=4321`